# How to store different copies of various fields of HTML page in Firebase?

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as a real time database for my app. Used JQuery in the JavaScript file.

This is the my Database structure in Firebase.

```
users
  |--- email: "pavan@gmail.com"
  |--- name: "pavan"
```

I'm able to store the values of `name` and `email` fields in my database. But, for every submission the previous values in the Firebase are overridden by the new values.

**My question is, how to store different copies of `name` and `email` field values in the firebase without overriding the previous values?**

These are the excerpts from my Application.

JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Submit Button 
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {

        var inputNameValue = $('#inputName').val();
        var inputEmailValue = $('#inputEmail').val();

        // Get a reference to the database service
        var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');

        // Setting the input field values into the database
        databaseRef.set({
            name: inputNameValue,
            email: inputEmailValue
        });

        // Empties the fields after pushing the data into firebase
        $('#inputName').val('');
        $('#inputEmail').val('');
    });

});
```

HTML file:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
        <h1 align="left">Firebase Web App</h1>
        <br>
        <div align="left" class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name">
        </div>
        <div align="left" class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
        <button id="submitBtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.8/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="firebase-init.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `push()` in order to store different copies of the fields in your database. Try this. It would definitely work!

```
databaseRef.push().set({
  name: inputNameValue,
  email: inputEmailValue
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`uid` is the name used by the Firebase Authentication system, namely, `.onAuthStateChanged` gets populated with a uid that is typically used with an `update` (not set).  So, most app's will have a structure like `users` and each child is a uid key.